# Why is the shading different on these two different parts of the same mesh?

Tags: modeling, shaders, lighting, topology, shadows

I modeled a Z GT500  front and as I cut gaps on this mesh to finish it I noticed it has a very different lighting/shading despite using the same material, correct face orientation, applied scale; unfortunately this is very visible in the game I import it to too. Happens with every MatCap and simple Studio lighting.

[image]
[image]

In the imported game (rear part significantly brighter):
[image]

Changing the UV Map doesn't change anything.

I include a .blend file with the parts that should shadow it too:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YhHdTOQUBBaDRoVLCQ62NDztvRVjTpm/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hello, you need to pack your image texture before sharing (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: I think it's only a matcap effect. In viewport shading mode, you don't have the same result as in rendered modes. But yes you should pack the textures as your material is texture based.

Comment: Hi, I replaced the file with packed textures, I hope I did it right.

Comment: All seems to be fine with the texture...

Comment: Yes this is the matcap you've chosen that create a big contrast between the faces, if it also happen in your game engine, maybe lower down the Specular IOR value so that it reflects less the lights?

Comment: Yes probably I have to tinker with the reflections and make the Ambient Occlusion darker on that part, seems to be the only solution, appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm sometimes wondering about these shading issues too when I'm modeling something, because it is actually not the _MatCap_ (sure, it increases the optical effect) because even if you choose the default _Studio_ lighting in _Solid_ view, there is still a brightness difference between the front and back part. However when you merge them together it is gone.